# Docusignapi Invalid_Request_Body XML how to encode special characters

Tags: docusignapi

How do I encode the special character within the XML for textTabs value.  for example

```
<text>
<tabLabel>Specifications</tabLabel>
<value>this isn’t the best type of board we need the "Strong Stuff"</value>
</text>
```

normally I would replace the special characters with the following

```
<text>
<tabLabel>Specifications</tabLabel>
<value>this isn&apos;t the best type of board we need the &quot;Strong Stuff&quot;</value>
</text>
```

But when I view the actual document with this value it is not translated back?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using escape sequences for the quotes (\"), basically like this:

```
<text>
<tabLabel>Specifications</tabLabel>
<value>this isn’t the best type of board we need the \"Strong Stuff\"</value>
</text>
```